# Raspberry Pi ZeroW - i can't acces from mobile (android)

Tags: networking, connection

I configured apache2 + php7 on Rpi Zero W, and I can access to the webserver using my PC by enter ip address of Rpi - but if I try to do that from mobile it fails...

Raspberry and phones are connected to the same WiFi network (router1), and PC is connected by cable (to router1). Every devices are on same network, same subnet etc... Tested on Firefox Mobile and Chrome Mobile.

```
Rpi - 192.168.1.252
PC: 192.168.1.106
Mob1: 192.168.1.104
Mob2: 192.168.1.105
```

I can ping: PC -> Mob1, PC -> Mob2, Mob1 -> PC, Mob2 -> PC
I can not ping: Mob1 -> Mob2, Mob2 -> Mob1

Comment: Can you ping Mob1 and Mob2 from the PC? Can Mob1 connect to Mob2 and wise versa?

Comment: I can ping 
    PC -> Mob1
    PC -> Mob2
    Mob1 -> PC
    Mob2 -> PC
    
    I can not ping:
    Mob1 -> Mob2
    Mob2 -> Mob1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems your router1 bridges completely only between ethernet and wifi and suppresses connections between devices on the wifi. This is an often used default security issue and can be configured on many routers. On my router I have the option to set *"clients can connect together on wifi"*. Look at your router if you find a similar option, mostly in section wifi.